Homology classes with local coefficients
In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology page 109 one can read:

In particular, elements of $H_1(X)$ are represented by collections of oriented loops
in $X$ , and elements of $H_2(X)$ are represented by maps of closed oriented surfaces
into $X$.

Does there exist a version of this statement for homology with local coefficients?

The statement about $H_2$ is unclear to me even when you use constant coefficients different from $\mathbb Z$, the first interesting case is $\mathbb Z/3$. (Hatcher only discusses integer coefficients on page 109.)

Just look at the UCT for 2nd homology with $\mathbb Z/3$-coefficients. How on earth one is supposed to interpret the $Tor$-part (if it is nonzero) using maps of closed surfaces? I think, you are chasing a phantom.

Right. With $\mathbb{R}$ coeffients it seems that one can come up with a statement, where you attach a real number to your closed surfaces. This make me think that it is an issue of torsion. What do you think?

With $\mathbb R$ twisted coefficients maybe. But for most applications one is interested in other $\mathbb Z G$-modules and issues will be similar even if there is no torsion.

Actually, even the case of flat real line bundles (which do not have compatible metrics) is unclear to me. But your question is too vague, try to formulate a precise conjecture you want to be true.
